# Verify password won't work perfectly using Bcrypt C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcrypt

I'm facing a real problem with the Bcrypt package, I have a piece of C# code that will hash the password and save it to the database and then get the password hashed and verify it with the entered password by the user if in the login window.

In simple case ( without storing in the database ) works fine, but when the password will be saved in the database, it causes problems.

```cs
var PasswordEncrypted = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(Password.Password);
userMdl.password = PasswordEncrypted;
bool testAdd = AddUser(userMdl);
if (test) 
{
    //....
}
else 
{
    //......
}

// And then save it to the database 

// Trying to get the password encrypted from the database
if(BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(passw.Password.ToString(), userMdl.password)
{
    Console.writeLine("Password correct");                   
}

public bool AddUser(UserModel model)
{
    string sqlconnection = GetConnection();
    using (IDbConnection connection = sqlconnection)
    {
        var p = new Dapper.DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("UserId",   model.UserID);
        p.Add( "password" ,  model.password);     
        try
        {
            connection.Query<UserModel>("dbo.User_insert", p, null, true, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GlobalConfig.log.Error("Problem when Add User " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

- The Column type of the password is `Nvarchar(Max)` and I've tried changing it to `Char(96)` but nothing changes
- The hashed password is shown in the table of the user.

What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: (reminder: hashing is ***not*** encryption.)

Comment: Hard to tell what you're doing wrong if you don't show any of the code that's doing the storing and retrieval, which is supposedly where the problem is.

Comment: Compare the hash from before it's saved to the database to what you get when you read it back. They should be identical, of course.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , I will try this

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , is not the same there are a little difference in the end

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @500-InternalServerError for helping, I finally solved it , the error was in the stored procedure , and the hash before save and after is not the same, so it saves only some characters,

When I change `nvarchar(55)` to `nvarchar(MAX)` of the column type of password and in the parameter of @password in the insert SQL procedure, it works.